# How to declare global variable with typescript check in JS file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript to do type checking of JS files (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html), by adding a `// @ts-check` comment to the top of the file.

It is complaining the a global variable (which I've assigned separately via `window`).

```js
// index.js

window.MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 42;

// module.js

console.log(MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE); // Error: Cannot find name 'MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE'.
```

How can I get rid of this error? I've tried adding the following comment

```js
/*
declare var MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE: number
*/
```

and

```js
/*
declare global {
  var MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE: number
}
*/
```

I've also tried adding those declarations to a `global.d.ts` file. But the checker is still complaining.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: See also https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15626

Comment: Thanks @cherryblossom for the link. That seems to be the same issue. However, the post implied that my `global.d.ts` workaround should've worked? But it doesn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your declarations in a shared file, such as `index.d.ts`. The TypeScript compiler will find it and take it into consideration when analyzing your JavaScript code.

### Example

**index.d.ts**

```
declare const MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE: number;
```

**module.js**

```js
console.log(MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE);
```

I also made a tutorial that shows how you can extend an existing module using [declare module](https://youtu.be/XoOgNRQEYws?t=835) in your `index.d.ts` file.